# AJAX atualizando a tabela errado

Tags: ajax, json

Tenho esta função AJAX para atualizar uma table, ela é desta forma:

```
 function incluirFornecedor(idItem) {
    var url = "/Produto/incluirFornecedorN";
    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , data: { id: idItem }
        , type: "POST"
        , datatype: "html"
        , success: function (data) {
            $("#tabelaf").html("");
            $(data).each(function () {
                $("#tabelaf").append("<tr><td>" + data.resultado + "</td><td>" + data.ProdutoID + "</td></tr>");
            });
        }
    });
}
```

E aqui é a função do controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult incluirFornecedorN(int id)
    {
        int produtoID = (db.Produtos.Max(a => a.Id) + 1);
        var fornecedor_produto = db.ProdutosFornecedores.Where(p => p.ProdutoID == produtoID).Where(p => p.FornecedorID == id).ToList();

        var item = new ProdutosFornecedores()
        {
            FornecedorID = id,
            ProdutoID = (produtoID)
        };

        return Json(new { Resultado = item.FornecedorID, item.ProdutoID });
    }
```

Só que ele aparece o id, eu queria que ele aparecesse o nome, igual está na tabela, segue o HTML:

```
 <table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="tabelaf">
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model.ProdutosFornecedores)
                            {
                                <tr class="tr">
                                    <td>@item.FornecedorProduto.Nome</td>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <a class="link-excluir" href="#" data-id="@item.Id" title="Excluir"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Ele trás o id, na ViewModel, tem a configuração para aparecer o nome corretamente, só que ao adicionar por ajax, ele não aparece.

Comment: No `controller` você só está retornando `id`. Você precisa adicionar o `nome` no retorno para poder utilizar na `view`.

Answer (score 1):

Em vez de:

```
var item = new ProdutosFornecedores()
    {
        FornecedorID = id,
        ProdutoID = (produtoID)
    };
```

Coloque algo como:

```
var item = new ProdutosFornecedores()
    {
        FornecedorProduto = fornecedor_produto,
        ProdutoID = (produtoID)
    };
```

E no retorno do JSON, referencie `FornecedorProduto`, e não `FornecedorId`.

Comment: O que aparenta, olhando o teu código, é que tu deve ta se confundindo ao passar o id, em vez do nome (que tu capturou para fornecedor_produto no controller).

Comment: Ele não aceita, ele me retorna o seguinte erro: Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "System.Collections.Generic.List<string>" em "Erp.Models.Fornecedor"